# Is it possible to completely disable phone calling on Android?

Tags: calls

I've disable the built-in phone app but an a voice over IP app took its responsibilities, I killed that too, disabled notification and tweak everything I could find except for turning off the ringtone in the settings and the phone will still ring, except I can't answer because there's no app for phone calls!

When I receive a phone calls there's a lingering notif as usual I always delete it along with the millions other notifs Android gets nonstop--it's really annoying, I never tapped on it because it does nothing, I remembered however that this version of Android brings more stuff at the first tap. I spent the last two hours trying to remember my own phone number to call myself and bring up the notification, upon tapping it it let me to the system app Phone Call Management which is not blockable. I want to reinstall my VoIP app, it requires to have a ringtone so it can ring too; is there another way around this?

BTW, I also installed phone call blockers, but don't really help in here.

Thanks!

[image: screenshot] [image: screenshot]

Comment: You can remove the SIM card or replace it with a data-only SIM if you don't want to make or receive phone calls at all.

Comment: If it is an LTE capable phone then set it to LTE only, when a person tries to call you it would seem as though you are busy and there wont be any ringing, you would still get SMS though

Comment: @AguThadeus Only of the carrier doesn't support VoLTE, although many do.

Comment: There is no such thing as a data-only card around here, they all incl unlimited all except for data--all carriers; funny thing is I want to limit all except for data. Carriers know people don't make calls/texts anymore, the only calls traversing their netwks are from other ops harassing customers to switch to their own crappy networks...and business calls which would fall under the latter category. Sometimes they manage to trick less savvy custmrs who are on a contract into switching and they make the switch and suddenly that user has to pay the remainder of his/her contract right away + fees.

Comment: "along with the millions other notifs Android gets nonstop" -> On the multiple Android phones I had, this wasn't the case. Don't blame Android for installing millions of apps.

Answer (score 0):

Try MTK Engineering kit. You can disable calls from that by turning radio off. Alternatively, use in dial pad `*#*#4636#*#*` and a window pops up. Now select phone information and scroll down to find the radio option. Now turn off the radio. Then you will not receive any calls. Otherwise you can use airplane mode as well.

Comment: If it turns radio off, it will also turn mobile data off. To achieve that, one can simply switch off the SIM in QuickSettings, or take the SIM out. But my guess is that's not what OP wants.

Answer (score 0):

I also have another method first open phone app also known as dialer now find settings from right up corner open the settings, now select call settings>call baring>all incoming calls now just disable them no call will come now but you can use your mobile data you also need barring password of your sim operator but in some cases it was 1234 or 0000 may you find this is in different way because difference of android but good luck.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be what I need. I can't change it though, I get and "Unexpected response from network" but just knowing the option is there I'm going to try to pressure my carrier on this. Thanks again!

Comment: Most welcome @Vita if this isn't help tell your device name ,andriod version and root or non rooted then i may help you.

Comment: There is one hack by which you can block your incoming calls.

Go to Settings -> Call settings -> Call forwarding
Now Click on Always forward and enable it to forward the calls to a wrong number.
This will ensure that calls will not come to you and the caller get the tone that call is being forwarded and number is wrong.

You can disable Call forwarding anytime you want.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem, no sound, but ringtones did work. I installed hangup call and a headphone switch to speaker... that did not work but it did tell me what the issue really was and it was this: the phone thought it was in call EVEN AFTER RESET AND FACTORY RESET...

The simple answer was put it into airplane mode. My phone was not on network so `#*#*` didnt work (code in other's post above). Gladly this was a half hour of this...

Side note: the battery was super draining so I kinda was suspicious of a radio like bluetooth or something being on but not notifying.

Comment: Putting the device in airplane mode cuts all network connections. Not sure if that's what the OP wanted.